# What are callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I ask a friend and ask what is `(data, function(i,e)` in this code and he said this is callback then i search the internet about callback and doesn't understand it. I read about this [What are callback methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324037/what-are-callback-methods)what is callback in simpliest way ?

```
 $.each(data, function(i,e){
   console.log(e.id);
 });
```

What is the use of `(data, function(i,e)` here?

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pbxApi+"/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid="+circle,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: "application/javascript",
        success: function(data) {

         console.log(data);

        }
        });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback method which is **called back**.

**Who calls it back at you ?**

Your framework calls it back.

**Why it calls it back ?**

Because you ask for it to get called back because you want to do some processing when something happens.

**Examples**

1. You are doing some processing and don't know when it completes. You provide a callback , and you continue with some other work. Your call-back function will be called back to tell you that processing is finished and you can do something at your end now.
2. You want to know when some control fires some event so that you can do some processing. You provide a call-back function as event handler.
3. You are not happy with default processing done by framework and want to override that processing, you provide a call-back and framework calls it back to use your own processing.

So, in general : You ask a component/framework to call your provided method. You never call that provided method from your code, someone else calls it back.

Answer (score 3):

A callback function is a function you specify to an existing function/method, to be invoked when an action is completed, requires additional processing, etc.

*Here's a little something for you to understand callbacks better:

Guy 1 to Guy 2: hey dude I wanna do something when a user clicks in there, call me back when that happens alright?

Guy 2 calls back Guy 1 when a user clicks here.*

Answer (score 1):

A callback function is a function that is passed to another function as a parameter, and the callback function is called (or executed) inside the another Function.
Like this

```
(data, function(i,e)
```

We can pass functions around like variables and return them in functions and use them in other functions. When we pass a callback function as an argument to another function, we are only passing the function definition.

Note that the callback function is not executed immediately. It is “called back” at some specified point inside the containing function’s body. For more info [Refer Here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, JavaScript statements are executed line by line. However, with effects, the next line of code can be run even though the effect is not finished. This can create errors.

To prevent this, you can create a callback function.

A callback function is executed after the current effect is finished.

For e.g, this is a call back function:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow", function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
});
```

In this case the function hide will be executed before that alert which is precisely what we want.

On the other hand if you don't use call back function say this way:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(1000);
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

In this case alert will be executed even before the function hide is executed. This is the typical use of callback function in Javascript.