# Java: Are abstract methods in awt listeners called callback methods?

Tags: java, callback, awt

The question is as the title goes. I'm slightly confused with the concept. For example, are methods like *void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)* also called callback functions in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that `actionPreformed` is a callback method due to the fact that the parameter is an `ActionEvent` object and not a function.

Callback methods usually refer to other methods and execute them.

*For instance:*

```
//note that this just a reference and not functioning code
public void callback(method, parameters) {
    method(parameters)
}

callback(System.out.println, "Hello World")
```

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324037/what-are-callback-methods#4324112) to another question that might help.

Comment: Are there many definitions to what a "callback" is in programming? There seems to be ways to implement callback in Java that do not necessarily pass methods(or functions) as parameters.