# How to run a function only when data is received from an xmlhttp call?

Tags: javascript

How can run an init() function that sets an innerHTML on my dom only when my getData() functions returns the array?

I am pretty sure i will need to have some kind of async await function here, but i am learning closures 
 at the same time and not sure how can i do this.

Code would like something like this:

```
const uiController = (function () {
  let data;

  const getData = async () => {
    const xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        data = getArray(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      }
    };

    xml.open("GET", "data.json", true);
    xml.send();


  };

  getData();


  // I only want init to run when getData() is finished and my data variable is updated with the fetched data. 

  // Something similar to react ComponentDidMount
  const init = () => {

  document.getElementById("article-grid").innerHTML = `<div>${data}</div>`

  }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are callback methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324037/what-are-callback-methods)

Comment: You can call the init function after you assign a value to your data variable. Unless your getArray function is async as well then you will need to handle that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const uiController = (function () {
let data;
// Something similar to react ComponentDidMount
const init = () => {
  document.getElementById("article-grid").innerHTML = `<div>${data}</div>`
}
const getData = async () => {
  const xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xml.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      data = getArray(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      init(); // call inside readyState === 4 
    }
  };

  xml.open("GET", "data.json", true);
  xml.send();
};

getData();
```

Comment: just a suggestion, make use of `fetch` instead of XmlHttpRequest

Comment: Thank you think this is what i was looking for.

I was trying to keep it the other way around, getData being called by init, as i was thinking about using Init to set up more stuff when document loads.

I just came back to the basics after struggling a bit with react and thats why i am using xmlhttp still, learning all the old stuff before moving onto the new stuff

Many thanks this helps a lot!

Comment: Why do I need the async in this case? tried without it and seems to working fine as well